# calculate time difference in minute between each record in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

```
Event   Startdatetime          Enddatetime            Value
1       '23/09/2016 12:15:20'  '23/09/2016 12:34:30'  50
1       '23/09/2016 14:10:40'  '23/09/2016 14:30:25'  40
2       '25/10/2016 10:20:45'  '25/10/2016 10:45:55'  80
2       '25/10/2016 11:27:35'  '25/10/2016 11:48:55'  30
```

Each record has startdatetime and enddatetime and I'd like to calculate time difference in minute between each record in group (by event).

Comment: Are these actually `DATETIME` values?  They look like `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't do this with `DATEDIFF()`?   And what are you calling a "group" in this question?  What would be the desired results for your sample data?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Startdatetime,Enddatetime)` would do. Or `DATEDIFF(SECOND,Startdatetime,Enddatetime)/60`

Answer (score 1):

Since that isn't a SQL Server recognized date format, you need to convert it first then do your math. You can use `LAG` to get the previous record with SQL 2012 onward.

```
   select datediff(mi,convert(datetime,Startdatetime,103),convert(datetime,lag(Enddatetime) over (order by Startdatetime),103))
```

or if it doesn't need converting...

```
select datediff(mi,Startdatetime,lag(Enddatetime) over (order by Startdatetime))
```

if you are only looking to do the time calculation on the event then you can partition off that as well...

```
select datediff(mi,Startdatetime,lag(Enddatetime) over (partition by Event order by Startdatetime))
```

Comment: In real case its date format column so I dont have an issue with date format.

Comment: @Tony if it is in datetime it wouldn't look like what you posted, so you had to change that, but you can remove the conversion if you'd like and use lag.

Comment: Again this just example in real case its date format, for now I need just what I mentioned before: need datediff between startdatetime of following record and enddatetime previous record.

Comment: @Tony... what i posted will work. i posted the same solution without the conversion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help scsimon, I dont have sql server to test right now, will test it tomorrow and let you know. Actually in real case I need to capture records has datediff less than 15 min, lets say next few records have datediff less than 15 min so I capture min startdatetime and max enddatetime then if next record has more than 15 this record stays the same.